# Powershell how to convert Chinese punctuation to English punctuation

Tags: powershell

We use powershell to do xml parsing. But as the xml file contains Chinese punctuation, the powershell always threw exception that  "could not convert System.Object[] to System.Xml.XmlDocument". So we want to replace all the Chinese punctuation to English punctuation before parsing the xml.

So how can we convert Chinese punctuation to English punctuation such like from "，" to ","? Thanks a lot

Comment: Please try to provide an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or as close as you can get to one.

Comment: Please _edit the question, do not use a comment_ and add some sample data that contains also some problematic punctuation characters.